# Управление SVG-координатами `path` с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg

У меня есть `path` SVG со следующими точками в атрибуте `d`.

Есть ли способ изменять только одно из координатных чисел в 'd', скажем, как 0 в `"L25 0"`, чтобы манипулировать в сценарии JavaScript?
Если это возможно, то как бы выглядел этот синтаксис?

Я хочу получить доступ к одному из координатных чисел, чтобы я мог увеличить его,  и тем самым анимировать `path`.

```js
function NavHalf() {
  var arrow = document.getElementById("arrowUp");
  arrow.setAttribute('d', 'M0 25 L25 0 L50 25');
}
```

```html
<svg height="25" width="50" onclick="NavHalf()">
   <path id="arrowUp" d="M0 0 L25 25 L50 0 " style="stroke:green;stroke-width:2; fill:none" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Manipulating SVG Path Coordinate with Vanilla JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58459580/7394871) от участника  [@Nhan Bui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11003564/nhan-bui).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/58459580/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Часть 2*

### Стандартный JavaScript

Упростить работу с отдельными значениями координат `path` можно и на чистом JS, без зависимостей. Например, можно добавить недостающее DOM-свойство `d`, и перехватывать обращения к нему используя `Proxy` (ES6+).

Следующий пример демонстрирует визуализацию частот во время воспроизведения звукового файла. Отрисовка линии выполняется через `path` (130 точек):

```js
function attributesSerializer(element, attributes) {
  return new Proxy(element, {
    get(el, prop) {
      if (prop === '$attrs') return this.$attrs; 
      if (this.$attrs[prop]) return this.$attrs[prop]; 
      const val = el[prop]; 
      return (typeof val === 'function') ? val.bind(el) : val; 
    }, 
    set(el, prop, val) {
      if (prop in this.$attrs) return false; 
      return ((el[prop] = val), true); 
    }, 
    $attrs: attributes.reduce((r, { attr, delim=' ' }) => {
      r[attr] = new Proxy({}, {
        get(obj, i) {
          const values = element.getAttribute(attr).split(delim).map(v => v.trim()); 
          return values[i];
        }, 
        set(obj, i, newVal) {
          const values = element.getAttribute(attr).split(delim).map(v => v.trim()); 
          values[i] = newVal; 
          element.setAttribute(attr, values.join(delim)); 
          return true;
        }
      }); 
      return r; 
    }, {}) 
  }); 
}

const path = attributesSerializer(document.querySelector('path'), [
  { attr: 'd', delim: '\n' }
]); 
let analyser, bufferLen, freqData;

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', e => {
  const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
  audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
  audio.load();
  const ac = new AudioContext(),
        src = ac.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  analyser = ac.createAnalyser();
  src.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(ac.destination);
  bufferLen = (analyser.fftSize = 512) / 2;
  freqData = new Uint8Array(bufferLen);
  audio.play();
  loop();
});

function loop() {
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqData);
  path.d[0] = `M0,100 0,${100 - freqData[0] / 2.55}`;
  for (var i = 2; i < bufferLen; i += 2)
    path.d[1 + i / 2] = `${100 * i / bufferLen},${100 - freqData[i] / 2.55}`;
  path.d[i] = 'L100,100 Z';
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

```css
body { display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; align-items: stretch; height: calc(100% - 32px); }
svg { align-self: center; width: 100%; max-width: 400px; height: 100px; outline: 1px dashed #ccc; }
input { margin: 0.5rem 0; }
audio { width: 100%; outline: none; }
input:invalid + audio { display: none; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="" fill="#def" stroke="#00f" stroke-width="0.1" />
</svg>
<input type="file" accept="audio/*" required>
<audio controls></audio>
```

Здесь функция `attributesSerializer` возвращает экземпляр `Proxy`, привязанный к DOM-объекту элемента `path`.
Этим прокси мы ловим только обращения к добавленному свойству `d` - которое так же отслеживается через прокси (вложенный), что позволяет считывать и присваивать значения отдельных точек в одноименном атрибуте через квадратноскобочную нотацию вида `pathElement.d[индексТочки]`.
В качестве символа-разделителя для (де)сериализации атрибута используется символ `\n`.

---

Такой подход обладает рядом недостатков. Основными минусами реализации являются ее относительная сложность, низкое быстродействие, и то что она является "велосипедом".

Поэтому, для решения таких задач, всегда лучше использовать реактивность. Ведь инструменты которые ее реализуют, предоставляют также массу других возможностей, помимо работы с атрибутами SVG.

Comment: Оффтоп: почему я здесь режу график значений частот из `getByteFrequencyData` справа, и почему он не совпадает с аналогичными в аудиоплеерах:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50879128 (en)

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле нет никакого основанного на DOM способа прямого доступа и манипулирования только одной из точек в определении пути.

Манипулирование строками - это все, что вы можете сделать.

```js
function NavHalf(x,y) {
  var arrow = document.getElementById("arrowUp");
  arrow.setAttribute('d', 'M0 0 L' + x + ',' + y + ' L50 0');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="NavHalf(25,0)">Position 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="NavHalf(20,15)">Position 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="NavHalf(25,25)">Position 3</button>

<svg height="25" width="50">
   <path id="arrowUp" d="M0 0 L25 25 L50 0" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:2; fill:none" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58471614/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

*Часть 1*

Так как значение отдельной координаты здесь не является объектом/свойством DOM, прямые манипуляции с этим значением в JS невозможны - вместо этого мы манипулируем атрибутом, изменяя его строковое значение.
И, существует...

### Типовой подход - реактивные библиотеки, фреймворки

*(только критика, без примеров)*

Сейчас уже мало кто пишет голый JS для решения подобных задач: распространена практика использования реактивных библиотек, чтобы упростить работу - и писать меньше кода, тем самым облегчая его поддержку.
Ну, так это ***должно*** работать...
Посмотрим как это выглядит для начинающего:

Для начала, нужно выбранную библиотеку подключить. Или две библиотеки, в случае реакта. Теперь страничка грузится чуть дольше. Хм, ну ладно, вроде мелочь - можно потерпеть ради преимуществ.
Далее надо написать бойлерплейт-код, в который поместим ту логику связи с DOM, которую мы хотим. *Тут уже возникает смутное ощущение, что...* а, неважно. Напишем. Мыжпрограммисты, в конце концов.
Но как-то это не очень удобно, в разметке набирать. Перенесем код в отдельный модуль - и бандлером будем все вместе собирать. Вебпак, то что нужно! Поглядим как его настраив... оооо... нет, *НЕТ*, мы не будем его настраивать. Все ж работает, да? Вот и хорошо, вот и славно.
Чтобы быстрее оправиться от психической травмы нанесенной вебпаком, изучим и применим TS - не надо будет сильно думать о логике выражений с типкастом. В самом деле, пусть машина думает, а нам и бойлерплейтов хватает... ведь мы уже по уши в фреймворке.

Вышло так, что в попытке упростить свою работу, мы ее ***усложняем***.
Инструменты, призванные помочь сконцентрироваться на программировании, уводят все дальше от программирования: мы npm install половину задач, и зависимы от внутренней магии готовых решений.
Экономия времени и совершенствование библиотек это в целом хорошо, если бы разработчики не забывали язык(!) и не теряли гибкость ума, попадая в ловушку бездумного потребления.

Многобукв, но зачем? Просто этим подвожу к альтернативному варианту, который вдохновляет лично меня. К варианту, который хотя бы частично вернет мотивацию вникать, понимать, развивать фундаментальные навыки - и к отказу от "жизни в фреймворке", в пользу реализации реактивности *на уровне языка*.
Этот вариант существует больше на уровне идеи, но есть несколько первых попыток ее воплотить. Здесь упомяну только одну молодую реализацию, а именно...

### Svelte

```html
<svg height="25" width="50" on:click={toggle}>
   <path d="M0 0 L25 {$midY} L50 0" style="stroke:green; stroke-width:2; fill:none;" />
</svg>

<script>
  import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';
  import { cubicOut } from 'svelte/easing';

  const midY = tweened(0, { duration: 250, easing: cubicOut });
  const toggle = () => midY.set($midY ? 0 : 25);
</script>
```

[<kbd>`Попробовать в REPL  ‎`</kbd>](https://svelte.dev/repl/0e65bcbd701d4f3985bb672836eeacc8?version=3.12.1)

Здесь мы связываем значение в атрибуте с переменной `midY`, которая плавно (необязательный бонус) меняет значение в функции `toggle`. 
Код выглядит изящно, работает быстро, и не будет утяжелять страницу.
А главное - Svelte не очередной фреймворк, это транслятор (компилятор). Его синтаксис переводится в стандартный JavaScript, который можно изучить и понять, если захочется.
То есть, это тоже магия, но она значительно ближе к разработчику. И хотя бандлер по-прежнему требуется (как минимум для трансляции), все же сделан [большой шаг в идеологии реактивности](https://youtu.be/AdNJ3fydeao), и в избавлении от бойлерплейтов - пишем только логику.

Данный пример очень прост, а вся мощь реактивного программирования раскрывается только в более сложных задачах (как многие из нас уже знают, применяя например RxJS к данным и событиям).
Но и такие вот маленькие задачи по-прежнему выигрывают: в читаемости кода, а также в скорости и весе, по сравнению с React и Vue.

Можно ли использовать Svelte в продакшене - *пока что* нет: технология очень вкусная, но местами еще не просушена, и экосистема только зарождается (до третьей версии проект был мало кому известен).
Стоит ли [ознакомиться](https://svelte.dev/) и держать руку на пульсе - определенно ***да***. Если даже Svelte будет незаслуженно брошен сообществом, схожие принципы используются в проекте Stencil (от Google).

---

Ответ получился рекламным, поэтому возможные минусы и тревоги будут встречены с пониманием.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, первый абзац ответа, и пример ниже - не отвечают на вопрос? Переменная `midY` в примере связана с DOM, изменение ее значения из JavaScript изменяет значение точки в атрибуте (в разметке).

Comment: Отвечает.. но вы видимо не поняли меня Я просто хотел другой пример, с другими цифрами, более сложный по наполнению

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, это да, было бы здо́рово)) Но честно говоря, я уже выдохся сегодня, и не уверен что осилю - SVG сложная штука для меня. Попробую изобразить на голом JS, через стандартный апи веб анимации... если второй ответ не появится, значит черезчур сложная)

Comment: я подожду, сколько потребуется Уверен, что будет интересно